# Uninstall SonicWALL GVC

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn, uninstall

Ever wondered how to uninstall broken SonicWALL GVC client on windows machine?

After trying the SonicWALL clean up tool and CCleaner we still have the error "Previous version installed, please remove before you continue".

Here is the below solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the windows command line you can use to uninstall the GVC.

MsiExec.exe /X{5E2D889D-FAFC-4E76-A851-3695ABA1A76F}

Let me know if this works for you.